# Onfido sandbox error 422 Unprocessable Entity Validation

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to create a check in Onfido sandbox environment and it's working fine when I use curl or python code while I'm receiving error 422 when I do the same request using swift from iOS.
here is the code that is confirmed to work in python:

```
def identity_check(self, applicant_id: str) -> dict:
        return self._post(
            'applicants/{}/checks'.format(applicant_id),
            data={
                'type': 'express',
                'reports[][name]': 'identity',
                'reports[][variant]': 'kyc',
            }
        )
```

and this is the swift code that gives me error 422:

```
 func executeCheck() {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "Token token=\(token)",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        ]
        let parameters: [String: Any] = [
            "type": "express",
            "reports[][name]": "identity",
            "reports[][variant]": "kyc"
        ]
        Alamofire.request(
            "https://api.onfido.com/v2/applicants/\(self.applicantId)/checks",
            method: .post,
            parameters: parameters,
            encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
            headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { (response: DataResponse<Any>) in
                guard response.error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                self.saveCompletedDocumentState()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular issue is to do with a misuse of Alamofire, particularly on the nesting of `'reports[][name]': 'identity'`. You should nest by having a sub object, `"reports": ["name": "identity"]`.

However, the recommended approach to start onfido checks is to do them on the backend.
Also, any questions with api can be answered by Onfido Tech Support here api@onfido.com